# how to access s3 bucket from aws workspace

Tags: amazon-web-services, workspace

I have created a windows aws workspace and installed aws cli inside it

Now I want this aws workspace to be able to access an s3 bucket. I dont want to use the aws secret and key thing. Instead use role which have Internally access to the S3 bucket

If this possible

Comment: No, there is no option to do this. You will need to use `aws configure` to store an Access Key and Secret Key locally on the Workspace.